# ElasticSearch/Kibana: how to aggregate similar type of pages

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Brand new kibana user, I am trying to track the usages on my site.

I have some pages in the follow type of url:

```
https://example.com/services/{serviceId}/users
```

so the serviceId changes for each service, however I want to see how many people are going to the `/users` page of their service.

Is there a way to aggregate the count of that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that url is a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) type, you have the below mapping:

```
PUT my_url_index
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "url" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Docs:

```
POST my_url_index/_doc/1
{
  "url": "https://example.com/services/101/users"
}

POST my_url_index/_doc/2
{
  "url": "https://example.com/services/asdasd/users"
}

POST my_url_index/_doc/3
{
  "url": "https://example.com/services/555/users"
}

POST my_url_index/_doc/4
{
  "url": "https://example.com/users/4444/create"
}
```

*Note that I'm assuming you only one variation of URL where you have both `services` and `user` tokens in it.*

This below query should help you get the total count as well as the count like how many times each user has been going:

```
POST my_url_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(services) AND (users)",
      "fields": ["url"]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_users": {
      "terms": {                          <----- Note the logic mentioned here
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['url.keyword'].toString().substring(30, doc['url.keyword'].toString().indexOf('/users'));"
        }, 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 336,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,                             <---- total count 
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {                           <----- count of each user
    "my_users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "101",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "555",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "asdasd",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps and if you are looking for anything else.